# Object not queryable

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, linq

I have a database "Pubs" with a table "authors". I have made a dbml file from the database by dragging over "authors".

Here is the "Default.aspx.vb"

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Dim author As Object
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim db As New PubsContext
        Dim authors = From p In dbo.authors _
                       Select p

        GridView1.DataSource = author
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the class for it: "Class1.vb"

```
Partial Public Class PubsContext
    Dim authors As Object
    Public Function GetProductsByCategory(ByVal id1 As Integer) As IEnumerable(Of authors)
        Return From p In Me.authors _
               Where p.au_id = id1 _
               Select p
    End Function
End Class
```

Error code: 
"Expression of type 'Object' is not queryable.  Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ".

In references there is already a "System.Data.Linq". What should I do?

Comment: Where is `dbo` (in `_Default`) defined?

Answer (score 3):

Well this is the problem:

```
Dim authors As Object
```

That's just an object. What does it *mean* to call `Select`, `Where` etc on that? Where are you even giving it a value? Work out what the type should *really* be, make sure you give it an appropriate value to start with, and you should be fine.

It's not clear why you're introducing your own `authors` field at all, to be honest - I'd expect the generated context to have an `Authors` property of type `Table<Author>` or something similar.

(I note that you're also trying to set `GridView1.DataSource` to `author` rather than `authors`, by the way... Why are you doing that? What value are you expecting the `author` field in `_Default` to have?)